# RegGetValue cannot find name under current user?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am testing this function `::RegGetValue`. The code below returns success.

```
DWORD data_size = 0;
LONG result = ::RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                            _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\OUTLOOK.EXE"),
                            _T("Path"),
                            RRF_RT_REG_SZ, 
                            NULL, NULL,
                            &data_size);
```

But if I try to find different entry under current user, it fails even though the entry does exist.

```
DWORD data_size = 0;
LONG result = ::RegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                            _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"),
                            _T("OUTLOOK.EXE"),
                            RRF_RT_REG_SZ, 
                            NULL, NULL,
                            &data_size);
```

Comment: Is the problem that it is not opening the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` key, that it is not finding the `OUTLOOK.EXE` value within it, or that it is not reading the value's data? Three different possibilities. What is the actual value of `result` on failure? It will tell you what is actually happening. Also, on my system, I don't have an `OUTLOOK.EXE` value in the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` key, but the values that I do have are all Dword values, not String values. Does the code work if you change `RRF_RT_REG_SZ` to `RRF_RT_REG_DWORD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the values in the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` key are DWORD values, not String values, per MSDN documentation:

[Internet Feature Controls (B..C): Browser Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser-emulation)

By specifying `RRF_RT_REG_SZ`, you are telling `RegGetValue()` to read only String values.  That makes sense when reading a `"Path"` value from the `App Paths` key, but when reading from the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` key you need to specify `RRF_RT_REG_DWORD` instead.